# best cloud computing company for webhosting business

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-computing, azure, rackspace-cloud

I'm running a reseller business. but now I have plans to expand it to the clouds. can you suggest some economical options for the same. most of them would be running wordpress and joomla. as far as I feel all the big names like microsoft azure,  amazon, rackspace, vmware have good quality service. I know linux but am not a that high server administrator. So which one should I go for.?

Comment: The FAQ recommends against this type of question.  You may wish to give it a read.

Comment: Yes, this particular question is another very wide-ranging one (as in 'how long is a piece of string ?'), but I do like the 'expand it to the clouds': that soundbyte should be part of a Haiku about Fukushima-Daichi :-P Yes, I'll get my coat.

Comment: Agree with the two comments above. Too vague and can't be answered.

Comment: i don't mind if its vague for you... :) cause thats what i want to know.

Comment: what i need is a small server in which i can run multiple wordpress instances. i want to know from senior admins who have used various cloud computing solutions for a advice of simple solutions in rackspace amazon etc and not a down vote from idiots...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not a server administrator you probably don't want to look at a generic "cloud service provider" like Amazon or Rackspace, because they won't give you any assistance with the management of your server.  You're probably better off with some sort of hosted service provider, where the service company is largely responsible for the installation and maintenace of the server and you are primarily working with the just your application.

If you're going to be working extensively with Wordpress, you may want to consult the [list of Wordpress hosting providers](http://wordpress.org/hosting/]) on the Wordpress website.  I'm not aware of a similar resource for Joomla, but the [Joomla forums](http://forum.joomla.org/) may be a better place for this question than ServerFault.

Comment: thanks. but not exactly limited to wordpress. what i need is a small server. in which i can run multiple wordpress instances. i want to know from senior admins who have used various cloud computing solutions for a advice.